# Restoring API Gateway Resource from previous Deploy

Tags: aws-api-gateway

```
/r1
 |- POST <-- accidentally deleted, want to restore
 |- GET <-- new method, will remove the POST from the previous deploy
```

One of the methods in one of our resources has been deleted. The resource is of course still in the most recent deploy, and we want to restore it so we can add, say, a GET method to the same resource.

If we just add the new GET and deploy, the POST will be removed. Is there no way to save and restore an API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. You may want to manage your API moving forward using a Swagger or RAML definition and using the [API import tool](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-importer). Doing so will allow you to treat your API definition like source code, with tracking and ability to revert changes.

Comment: Thanks, I agree. I was dearly hoping for something, maybe just swagger export functionality in API Gateway.

Comment: This answer is out of date; crazypython's answer is correct.

Answer (score 15):

2017- You can now export a stage as Swagger + API Gateway Extensions (Stages > [your stage] > Export > Swagger + API Gateway Extensions)and import it through Actions > Import API

Answer (score 14):

You can easily restore your `AWS API Gateway` from a previous deployment. Go to `API Gateway` and select your `API`. Then select `Stages`. Pick a stage that has the last version of your deployment that you want to restore. Select it and click the `Export tab`, and export the `JSON + Swagger` file. Then select the `Resources` tab and under `actions` click `Import`. Once you import your swagger file, your `API Gateway` resources will be restored to the version that was deployed to that aforementioned `Stage`. I hope this helps.

Comment: I just did this and now all my methods in Resources disappeared. You've gotta be kidding me.

Comment: Oh you have to select: "Export as Swagger + API Gateway Extensions"

Answer (score 2):

We can restore the previous state of the API gateway by changing deployment. If any resource is deleted then we can't restore that resource under API gateway `Resources`. but we can restore the previous deployment state and Also, we can export the restored deployment state using the `Export` option in `Stages`. You can see in the image that we can restore by choosing deployment and click on `Change Deployment`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use the CLI tool to retrieve configuration details for your deployed API ([Get-Deployment CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-deployment.html)).

aws apigateway get-deployment --rest-api-id "value" --deployment-id "value"

The output contains a field "apiSummary" which will show you some details about the api configuration.

Best,
Jurgen